# How to spyOn a function created inside the Jasmine beforeEach block of code?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This is my code:

```
describe('Factory: BaseService', function() {
    var fctry, mockBackend;

    beforeEach(function() {

        module('BaseApp');

        cb = function() {};

        inject(function(_BaseService_, _$httpBackend_) {
            mockBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            BaseService = _BaseService_;
        });
    });

    it('logout() should POST to /logout', function() {
        spyOn(BaseService, 'accessErrors').and.callThrough();
        spyOn('cb');
        mockBackend.expectPOST("/logout").respond(404, {msg: 'Not Found'});

        BaseService.logout(cb);

        mockBackend.flush();

        expect(BaseService.accessErrors).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(BaseService.cerrorMessages).toEqual(['Not Found']);
        expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

When I run this test, I get an error which says:

```
Chromium 48.0.2564 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) Factory: BaseService logout() should POST to /logout FAILED
    Error: No method name supplied
```

and it points to the line `spyOn('cb')`. What is the correct way to spy on a function created in the `beforeEach` block of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `spyOn` should be used to remove a dependency -- It seems weird to me to spy on a function that is defined in the test itself.

In this case, I might just create a spy and pass it to `BaseService.logout` directly:

```
it('logout() should POST to /logout', function() {
    spyOn(BaseService, 'accessErrors').and.callThrough();

    // just create the spy here -- no need to create a function so you can replace
    // it with a spy via spyOn :-).
    var cb = jasmine.createSpy('cb');

    mockBackend.expectPOST("/logout").respond(404, {msg: 'Not Found'});

    BaseService.logout(cb);

    mockBackend.flush();

    expect(BaseService.accessErrors).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(BaseService.cerrorMessages).toEqual(['Not Found']);
    expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: thanks. Quick question though, what exactly do you mean by "Usually, spyOn should be used to remove a dependency"? Isn't spyOn used to spy on objects to see if they are called, and what they are called with?

Comment: what you've described is the functionality of a _spy_.  `spyOn` takes a dependency (e.g. a function attached to a controller or service or ...) and replaces it with a spy for the duration of the test.  Notice the difference?  In this case, you don't have a dependency to spy on -- You just want an object that tracks calls (a spy).

Answer (score 1):

You can only spy on an object, which is why the syntax for spyOn is:

```
objFoo = {};
objFoo.funcBar = function() {};

spyOn(objFoo, 'funcBar');
```

So create an object to contain your function.

Or spy on **window**, seeing as you made **cb** a global var:

```
spyOn(window, 'cb');
```

Though that's not really recommended :-)